# How to add Ok and cancel button in alert dialog with radio button

Tags: java, android

I have one fragment(fragment) and one dialog fragment(RadioListAlert). I want to add OK and Cancel button in my alert dialog. When click ok button that selectable item name passed to CarFragment . How to do.

My code here:

RadioListAlert.java:

```js
package com.h2o;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class RadioListAlert extends DialogFragment {

    CharSequence[] tag = { "BMW", "AUDI", "MERCEDES", "FERRARI", "SKODA" };

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("Tag Your Car").setSingleChoiceItems(tag, -1,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tag[which],
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

CarFragment.java:

```js
//Call RadioListAlert class
new RadioListAlert().show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Radio Alert");
```

Please anyone help me!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can set a positive and negative button:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //your code to pass a bundle to fragment
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //do what you want when cancel is clicked
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use method `setNegativeButton()` and `setOnPositiveButton` to add Ok and cancel buttons.
To send the data to your fragment, you will need to create an interface which will hold that data and your fragment will implement it. it will be something like `new RadioListAlert().setDialogListener(CarFragment.this).show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Radio Alert");`

Remember to call that listener when the `onClickListener` is called for **Ok** button for example before dismissing the dialog.

**EDIT**

```
public class RadioListAlert extends DialogFragment {

CharSequence[] tag = { "BMW", "AUDI", "MERCEDES", "FERRARI", "SKODA" };
private CarListener carListener;
private String itemClicked;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle("Tag Your Car").setSingleChoiceItems(tag, -1,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tag[which],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    itemClicked = (String) tag[which];
                }
            }).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
        {
            if(carListener != null)
                carListener.itemClicked(itemClicked);
            //to dismiss the dialog after user choose an item and click ok, you can also add some validation before dismissing the dialog
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}

public void setListener(CarListener carListener)
{
    this.carListener = carListener;
}


    public interface CarListener
    {
        void itemClicked(String text);
    }
}
```

in your carFragment implement the CarListner

Comment: Thank you.. Added ok and cancel button. But how to pass that item value to carFragment.. What i do

Comment: @Appu please check my Edit

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'itemClicked' and Cannot resolve symbol 'addressListener'.. What to do

Comment: Check the start of the class it is 2 variables that I have added to your class. It should be 'carListener' not 'addressListener'. Remember in your CarFragment to add it as listener using method setListener(this)

Comment: Now cleared... but only one doubt... Its shows setListener in never used in RadioListAlert.java:

Comment: in your fragment  new RadioListAlert().setListener(this).show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Radio Alert");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88262/discussion-between-m-baraka-and-appu).

Comment: In my fragment, new RadioListAlert().setListener(this).show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Radio Alert");     I got an error                                            particularly setListener(this)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    final View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myalert, null);
    builder.setView(mView);

    final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) mView.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            int checkedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) mView.findViewById(checkedId);
            Log.d("alert", checkedId+"");

            --------------- your code---------------
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

            --------------- your code---------------

        }
    });

    builder.show();
```

your custom alert dialogue layout is : myalert

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>
```